# Continuity of function in $R^2$ with $d_2$ metric

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $f:(R^2,d_2)\rightarrow(R^2,d_2)$ , where

$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
(x,y),& x,y\in Q\\
(0,0), & elsewhere
\end{cases}$

I have to prove that $f$ is continuous only in $(0,0)$. I have proved that $f$ is continuous in $(0,0)$ but I cant prove that $f$ is not continuous in $R^2-\{0,0\}$

**For the proof of continuity in $(0,0)$:**

Let $(x_n,y_n) \rightarrow (x_0,y_0)=(0,0)$

$|f(x,y)|_2\leq d_2(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2} ,\quad \forall(x,y)$

$|f(x_n,y_n)|_2\leq d_2(x_n,y_n)=\sqrt{x_n^{2}+y_n^2}$

$|f(x_n,y_n)|_2\rightarrow (0,0)$

So, proved that $f$ is continuous in ${(0,0)}$ .

Comment: To show that $f$ is not continuous at $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ consider two sequences $(x_k,y_k)\in \Bbb Q^2$ and $(\tilde x_k,\tilde y_k)\in \Bbb Q^2$ so that $x_k,\tilde x_k \to x$ and $y_k,\tilde y_k \to y$.

Comment: choose $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$ choose $\epsilon = \frac 12 d((x,y),(0,0))$  for any $\delta$ there exists an $(x',y'), (x'',y'')$ such that $(x',y')$ are both rational and $(x'',y'')$ are both irrational.  And for one of them $\|f(x,y) - f(x',y')\|$ or $\|f(x,y) - f(x'',y'')\|$ will be greater than $\epsilon.$

Comment: Every neighborhood of each (x,y) contains points (u,v) with u,v irrational.